# networkx subgraph isomorphism for disconnected graphs

Tags: graph-theory, networkx

Why does networkx think that the following two graphs are not isomorphic?

```
from networkx import nx
g1 = nx.empty_graph(2)   #just two unconnected nodes
g2 = nx.complete_graph(3)
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(g2,g1)
print(str(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic()))
```

Answer (score 1):

The subgraph being matched is a node-induced subgraph which also includes matching the edges.

So

```
from networkx import nx
g1 = nx.empty_graph(2)   #just two unconnected nodes                                                                                     
g2 = nx.complete_graph(3)
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(g2,g1)
print(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic()) # False
g3 = g2.subgraph(g1)
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(g2,g3)
print(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic()) # True, includes edge (0,1)
```

Comment: That does not really solve my problem. The reason I asked the question: Example: I have a graph G1 consisting of 2 disconnected K4s and I want to check whether another graph contains this subgraph, i.e. contains two separate (vertex disjoint) K4s. Is this possible with networkx?

Comment: Would it work to remove the first matched subgraph completely (including the nodes) and then match again with the remaining graph?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the correct function to use is `subgraph_is_monomorphic()`, not `subgraph_is_isomorphic()`.

According to the [documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.vf2.html#subgraph-isomorphism):

> Finally, the term ‘subgraph’ can have multiple meanings. In this context, ‘subgraph’ always means a ‘node-induced subgraph’. Edge-induced subgraph isomorphisms are not directly supported, but one should be able to perform the check by making use of nx.line_graph(). For subgraphs which are not induced, the term ‘monomorphism’ is preferred over ‘isomorphism’.
>
> If G’=(N’,E’) is a node-induced subgraph, then:
> N’ is a subset of N E’ is the subset of edges in E relating nodes in N’
>
> If G’=(N’,E’) is a monomorphism, then:
> N’ is a subset of N E’ is a subset of the set of edges in E relating nodes in N’

Therefore, the term *subgraph* in networkx is actually referring to *node-induced subgraph*. The *subgraph isomorphism* that the OP was looking for is actually *subgraph monomorphism* in networkx.

Therefore,

```py
import networkx as nx
g1 = nx.empty_graph(2)   #just two unconnected nodes
g2 = nx.complete_graph(3)
GM = nx.algorithms.isomorphism.GraphMatcher(g2, g1)
print(GM.subgraph_is_monomorphic())  # True
```